# How to compare two BSTRs or CComBSTRs?

Tags: c++, com, atl

What is the right way to compare two CComBSTRs? I tried to use

```
 bool operator ==(
     const CComBSTR& bstrSrc 
 ) const throw( );
```

However it always return false even two ComBSTRs are the same. It did not work correctly.

Do I have to convert **CComBSTRs** to ANSI string first and then use strcmp?

Thanks!

-bc

Comment: Note that when comparing `CComBSTRs` with `LPCSTR`, `CComBSTRs` must be on the left side. `ccom_bstr == null_terminated_str` compares the strings, but `null_terminated_str == ccom_bstr` compares the pointers. Same for `!=` and other operators.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably use [`VarBstrCmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221038.aspx).

EDIT: this is actually what `CComBSTR::operator==` does, so without further context, your code may be incorrect.

Comment: VarBstrCmp doesn't work either. It returns HRESULT 0x00000002 The system cannot find the file specified. My code is like:

CComBSTR m_bstrUrl;

......

HRESULT hr = ::VarBstrCmp( (BSTR)m_bstrUrl, pvURL->bstrVal, ::GetThreadLocale(), 0 );

Comment: what is the type of m_bstrUrl? why did you have to cast it to BSTR?

Comment: Read what MSDN says about the return result. The data type is an HRESULT but the meanings aren't HRESULT meanings.

Comment: Thanks all! Problem solved. The issue was the source string has two weird bytes appended. It is invisible for read, but is there in comparison. Trim out extra two bytes. Everything is fine.

Comment: @bionicoder: Are those extra bytes [Unicode BOM markers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), or [BSTR length prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323cefbf-836c-4c9d-bcbe-f2663a57d2b5(VS.85))?

Answer (score 2):

BSTRs (and therefore CComBSTRs) are usually Unicode strings. You can use wcscmp() (or wcsicmp() for case-insensitive comparison).

Beware that encapsulated BSTR can be null which is a legal representation for an empty string and this should be treated as a special case, otherwise your program might run into undefined behaviour (most likely just crash).

Answer (score 0):

To properly compare `BSTR` values which may contain embedded null characters you need to use something like this:

```
bool EqualBSTR(const BSTR String1, const BSTR String2, bool IgnoreCase = false)
{
    if (String1 == nullptr || String2 == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    const size_t MaxCount = std::min(static_cast<size_t>(SysStringLen(String1)), static_cast<size_t>(SysStringLen(String2)));

    if (IgnoreCase) {
        return _wcsnicmp(String1, String2, MaxCount) == 0;
    } else {
        return wcsncmp(String1, String2, MaxCount) == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
BSTRsAreEqual(BSTR bstr1, BSTR bstr2, VARIANT_BOOL* boolptrEqual)
{
   CString s1, s2;
   s1 = bstr1;
   s2 = bstr2; 
   if (s1 == s2) { 
      *boolptrEqual = true;   
   } else { 
      *boolptrEqual = false;    
   }
}
```